# How do you use a casted variable as a Type?

Tags: c#, types, casting

**EDIT**
Both questions don't answer mine. Perhaps a better way to approach this question:
**How do you use a casted variable as a Type?**
OR **How do you use a string cast to a type to declare a Type variable?**

Example, see:
 `Document document = ((document)modelObject);`

The Document type is used here, but say I didn't know my modelObject was a document, how would I obtain it?

Hypothetical imagined solution where t is Document

```
Type t = Type.GetType(type.Name);  
t tVar = ((t)modelObject);
```

In my example above, it does not work because *"'t' is a variable but is used like a type"*

**ORIGINAL**
I have a control structure that I want to use to handle varying types as they appear dynamically. These types are gathered with *type.Name* and then enter the control structure based on such. What I would like is to be able to do is keep the control structure for folders, so that I can continue handling the folder functionality (allowing the expansion of folders, etc), but generalize each other type so that they can all be handled in a single structure rather then copying the structure over and over but with the slight change of the type to be handled.

So, my structures look (roughly) like this:

```
Type type = modelObject.GetType();
if (type.Name == "Folder")
{
    Folder folder = ((Folder)modelObject);
    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(folder.Object_string);

    NewNode.Tag = folder;

    CurrentRootNode.Nodes.Add(NewNode);
    if (fRecursive)
    {
        ModelObject[] objects = { modelObject };
        String[] attributes = { "contents" };

        WorkspaceObject[] NewNodeContents = ((Folder)modelObject).Contents;

        AddContentsToNode(NewNode, NewNodeContents, true);
    }
    else
    {
        TreeNode EmptyNode = new TreeNode("");
        NewNode.Nodes.Add(EmptyNode);
    }
}

if (type.Name == "STL")
{
    STL stl = ((STL)modelObject);
    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(stl.Object_string);

    NewNode.Tag = stl;

    CurrentRootNode.Nodes.Add(NewNode);
}

if (type.Name == "Document")
{
    Document document = ((Document)modelObject);
    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(document.Object_string);

    NewNode.Tag = document;

    CurrentRootNode.Nodes.Add(NewNode);
}
```

Notice how the STL and Document types are handled exactly the same with the slight variation of changing what type they are handled as.
Ideally, it would look like this:

```
if (type.Name == "Folder")
{ ... }
else
{
    (Type)type.Name tn = (((Type)type.Name)modelObject);
    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(tn.Object_string);

    NewNode.Tag = tn;

    CurrentRootNode.Nodes.Add(NewNode);
}
```

However, as seen above, type.Name is a string.
(Type)type.Name text on hover - `Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Type'`

So the question is:

**Is there a "generic" way to convert string to Type, or assign Type based on a string?**

I can't seem to find any generic way to process the type declaration across the board (something like the *Ideally example* would be ideal!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While converting a string to a type is not all that difficult, I have to point out you are going about this the wrong way. You should never have to store a type in a string, just as you would never store a number in a string or a date in a string.

If you have a series of types to check for, and different actions for each, follow this pattern:

```
public void HandleModelObject(object modelObject)
{
    var folder = modelObject as Folder;
    if (folder != null)
    {
        TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(folder.Object_string);
        return;
    }
    var document = modelObject as Document;
    if (document != null)
    {
        TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(document.Object_string);
        return;
    }
    var someOtherType = modelObject as SomeOtherType;
    if (someOtherType != null)
    {
        TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(someOtherType.Object_string);
        return;
    }
}
```

In addition, I recommend that you add a common interface to all the objects that can appear in a tree node, e.g. `IExplorable` or something. Then you don't even have to cast:

```
interface IExplorable
{
    string Object_string { get; set; }
}

class Folder : IExplorable
{
    public string Object_string { get; set; }
}

class Document : IExplorable
{
    public string Object_string { get; set; }
}

public void HandleModelObject(IExplorable modelObject)
{

    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(modelObject.Object_string);  //No if or cast required at all
}
```

If you don't want an interface, and you want to be able to handle any object, the only properties you can use are `GetType()` and `ToString()`, which are common to all objects. The solution is very short:

```
public void HandleModelObject(object modelObject)
{
    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(modelObject.ToString());
}
```

If you only need to handle a subset of objects, but they don't have a common interface, but they do have a common property (e.g. `string Object_string`) then you could use a bit of reflection. This is a last resort.

```
public void HandleModelObject(object modelObject)
{
    var value = modelObject.GetType().GetProperty("Object_string", BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(modelObject) as string;
    TreeNode NewNode = new TreeNode(value);
}
```

Naturally you will need null checks in case you mistakenly provide the wrong type of object and it doesn't have an `Object_string` property.

Comment: Nothing is getting instantiated in either of my examples; it is called a cast, and is less expensive than the string comparison in your example.  But if you want to process them uniformly (recommended), see my second example.

Comment: The second example still requires adding the IExplorable interface to each different option of countless

Comment: Is that an issue? What kind of objects are we talking about here, anyway? Are these classes that you have written?

Comment: I was hoping for a single structure that could handle the rest as this is purely for displaying data in a tree.

Comment: Do you mean a single data structure or single code structure? You need to clarify what these objects are.

Comment: Single control structure, see my "Ideal solution" in the op. EX: If(folder), else(every other type). Simply because folders can be expanded while other types can't, and if I have to create control structures for each data type as well its highly redundant and not efficient

Comment: Right @jtth.  Still need to know about those types. Do you want to be able to handle any object at all? How do you know what property to pass to the `TreeNode`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) overloading, but you should use the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) and not Name, because name can result in ambiguity.

```
string type = typeof(Program).FullName;
var typeObj = Type.GetType(type);
```

Of course this will only give you the class type and not the actual instance.

Answer (score 0):

I could not convert my strings to types and then use them as types. From my research this isn't possible. The duplicate markings yielded no results either. Instead, the only workaround I could implement for now was adding TC-types as nodes directly w/o processing type beforehand.